# Scala: am I writing a curried function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, currying

I have to transform the following function into a curried function:

```
def findAllUsed(t: List[Task]): List[String] = {
    t.flatMap(x => x.resources.map(x => x.FIELD_TO_SEARCH)).distinct
}
```

So I did this:

```
def findAllUsed(t: List[Task], f: Resource => String): List[String] = {
    t.flatMap(x => x.resources.map(f)).distinct
}
findAllUsed(taskSchedules, ((x: Resource) => { x.id }))
findAllUsed(taskSchedules, ((x: Resource) => { x.kind }))
```

The problem is that it seems to me that I am confusing currying with higher order functions.

Can anyone if I am doing it right and if not, how could I manage to do it right?

Comment: The function is higher-order (takes a function as an argument) but it is not curried (it takes all of it's arguments at once).  What are you trying to accomplish with a curried version of this function?

Comment: I see...
Depending on the type of the input (x.id or x.kind) I have to return a list of the id's or kind's in the Task list.

Comment: Then they way you wrote it seems reasonable, and I see no need for currying.

Comment: Yes, probably there is no need to currying, but the thing is that in the exercise that I am doing, I must write a curried function.
Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @undisp you can't curry a function of 1 argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the exercise meant something like this:

```
// separate into two argument lists
def findAllUsed(t: List[Task])(f: Resource => String): List[String] = {
  t.flatMap(x => x.resources.map(f)).distinct
}

// apply the first argument list once, 
// getting a curried function as a result
val curried = findAllUsed(taskSchedules)

// now you can use it twice with different inputs for the second argument list:
curried(x => x.id)
curried(x => x.kind)
```

The benefit here (if there is any), is the removal of the duplication passing `taskSchedules` to your function: since it has "it's own" argument list, you can pass it once, assign the result into a value (`curried`), and then reuse it over and over;

p.s. the type of `curried` is `(Resource => String) => List[String]` - it's a function from a `Resource => String` (which is another function...) to a list of strings.

Comment: Perfect, helped me a lot. Thank you.